# Prove property of integral of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Going over some old notes, I came across the following problem:

> Let $f,g$ denote continuous real functions on $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$. Prove 
>     that 
>     $$f(x)\int_{a}^{x}g(t)\,dt \;=\; g(x)\int_{x}^{b}f(t)\,dt$$ 
>     has at least one solution on $(a,b)$.

Unfortunately, I have a note (in the margin no less!) that just says "proof follows from Rolle's theorem". Fortunately, this proof is easier than Fermat's Last Theorem, but I wouldn't mind someone checking my logic since it's a few months since doing the course.

**Proof**: We introduce the function:
$$\begin{aligned}
F:[a,b] &\;\longrightarrow\; \mathbb{R} \\
x &\;\longmapsto\; F(x) \;\equiv\; \left(\int_{a}^{x}g(t)\,dt\right)\left(\int_{x}^{b}f(t)\,dt\right).
\end{aligned}$$
From the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, the integral of a function continuous on $[a,b]$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. It follows from the product of continuous and differentiable functions that $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Furthermore, $F(a)=F(b)=0$ since the limits of one of the integrals in $F$ will be the same, and hence vanish, at $x=a$ and $x=b$. Thus, $F$ satisfies the requirements of Rolle's theorem and
$$\exists\, x_{0}\in(a,b) \quad\text{s.t.}\quad F'(x_{0})\,=\, 0.$$
From the Product Rule and the Leibniz Integral Rule, we have
$$\begin{aligned}F'(x) &\;=\; \frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{a}^{x}g(t)\,dt\right)\cdot\left(\int_{x}^{b}f(t)\,dt\right) + \left(\int_{a}^{x}g(t)\,dt\right)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{x}^{b}f(t)\,dt\right) \\[0.3cm]
&\;=\;  g(x)\int_{x}^{b}f(t)\,dt - f(x)\int_{a}^{x}g(t)\,dt
\end{aligned}$$
and hence there exists at least one $x_{0}\in(a,b)$ such that
$$\begin{aligned}
F'(x_{0})\,=\, 0 \quad&\Longrightarrow\quad  g(x_{0})\int_{x_{0}}^{b}f(t)\,dt - f(x_{0})\int_{a}^{x_{0}}g(t)\,dt \;=\; 0 \\[0.3cm]
&\Longrightarrow\quad  g(x_{0})\int_{x_{0}}^{b}f(t)\,dt \;=\; f(x_{0})\int_{a}^{x_{0}}g(t)\,dt
\end{aligned}$$
and the result follows. $\;\blacksquare$

I get the feeling that I probably put too much into a proof - but it's good for my own sanity so that I know precisely what's going on and I don't run into the problem (like now!) of remembering precisely the logic. Thoughts welcome!

Comment: Well written, keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed a correct proof; perhaps what makes it feel a little long is your exact explanation of why you are allowed to use certain theorems, but that only makes it nicer and more rigorous. The further you go in mathematics, some of these things won't be worth mentioning, but for now, certainly a nice proof!

Comment: Thank you - it's really for me rather than to be graded. Would it be okay to omit explanations in exams/coursework? It would save me time also!

Comment: @AloneAndConfused It does show you have a good grasp of what's going on and can put it to words. I personally would've shorted it a little; for instance, simply saying 'hence F is differentiable on $(a,b)$' instead of the slightly longer explanation, but overall, it's still nicely dense.